# Вводное внутри цитаты

Tags: вводные-слова

*Валерий Сюткин рассказал, наконец, почему «конечно, Вася».*

Нужна ли запятая перед кавычками, чтобы отделить вводное слово слева?

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: Валерий Сюткин рассказал наконец, почему «конечно, Вася».

Кажется, вот адрес форума, где обсуждался  вопрос **о запятой в начале цитаты**: [Обособленный оборот в начале цитаты | gramota.ru](http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?p=290116)

Скорее всего, что по-разному должны оформляться два сходных приложения:

(1) Я думаю, что, создавая что-то новое, необязательно разрушать старое.

(2) Он сказал, что "создавая что-то новое, необязательно разрушать старое".

Вообще говоря, если цитата, взятая из середины авторского текста, встраивается в другой текст, то **ее начальные и конечные запятые не обозначаются в новом тексте, но внутренние знаки полностью сохраняются** (от этом, кажется, говорится в правилах Лопатина и Розенталя).

Если во втором предложении поставить запятую после ЧТО, то эта запятая (обособление деепричастного оборота) будет относиться **к структуре предложения**, а вторая запятая при этом находится **внутри цитаты**, то есть мы объединяем структуры предложения и цитаты, а это недопустимо (всё, что находится в кавычках, рассматривается как единое и неприкосновенное целое).

Comment: *Кажется, вот адрес форума, где обсуждался вопрос о запятой в начале цитаты:*  - да, спасибо! Именно оно. Только меня с грамоты поперли, я теперь не могу там ориентироваться, как привык.

Answer (score 2):

> Валерий Сюткин рассказал, наконец, почему «конечно, Вася».
>   Нужна ли запятая перед кавычками, чтобы выделить вводное слева?

-???

Перед кавычками - это после почему??? Там она даже в страшном сне не приснится. Ну еще "Вася" может быть обращением, а может и не быть, как и "конечно" может не быть вводным, но это я оставляю любителями казуистики.

Здесь есть только одна сомнительная запятая - перед наконец, там она скорее всего действительно лишняя. "Наконец" здесь в наречном значении (="в конце концов"), вряд ли вводное, поэтому запятая не нужна.

Мой вариант:
***Валерий Сюткин рассказал наконец, почему «конечно, Вася».***

//===

> И хотя есть правило, что перед цитатой, начинающейся не с начала >предложения, ставится тот знак, который там нужен по смыслу, см. здесь, >этот случай сюда не подпадает.

Вы приводите совершенно неприемлемую по причине двусмысленности формулировку. И очень хорошо, что потом от неё отказываетесь. Во-первых, не по смыслу, а по структуре предложениz, но это ладно. А во-вторых, по этой ясамой структуре, знака-то и не требуется. Речь не о том, что знаки те же, какими они бы были без кавычек, это неверное понимание. Структура предложения - это то, какую грамматическую роль выполняет объект, заключенный в кавычки. У Розенталя он по умолчанию выполняет роль придаточного, поэтому запятая стоит.

Года два назад здесь или где-то еще, помню, меня в асфальт чуть не закатали с этой запятой именно из-за неверно понятого Розенталя, но чем больше закатывали, тем больше я убеждался, что мои оппоненты неправильно трактуют Розенталя (и не только его). Если тот разговор найду - дам ссылку.
Но могу и своими словами, по Розенталю. Чуть изменим:

*Вспомните фразу(,) "Как хороши как свежи были розы".*

Ну здесь-то ясно, что в кавычках никакое не придаточное, а обычное приложение. Фразу - какую? А теперь представьте, что слово "фраза" убрана, оно выполняет роль этакого родового слова (как *колхоз* "Красный Октябрь"), понятно, что .

*Вспомните [колхоз] "Красный Октябрь" - Вспомните [фразу] "Как хороши, как свежи были розы".* - При таком в**и**денье грамматик запятая совершенно лишняя даже в варианте Розенталя.

И вот об этом, мне кажется, и говорится у Розенталя. Запятая ставится в зависимости от того, как ***понимаетcя*** структура фразы.

А совсем не от того, как она будет выглядеть без кавычек.

Т.е. у нас запятой однозначно не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что не нужна. "Конечно, Вася" - это как бы единый элемент. У вводного слова *конечно* нет связи с остальными членами предложения. И хотя есть правило, что перед цитатой, начинающейся не с начала предложения, ставится тот знак, который там нужен по смыслу, см. [здесь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=178#pp178), этот случай сюда не подпадает. "Конечно, Вася" отвечает на один вопрос. Запятая, ставится перед открывающими кавычками, обозначающими цитату, когда она необходима по структуре предложения.

Answer (score 1):

Слушайте, этот ответ будет противоречить моему предылущему. Поэтому и делаю отдельно. Не др конца противоречить, но все же.

Дело в том, что При такой орфографии ("конечно" - со строчной) очень может быть, что и запятая понадобится. Если "конечно Вася" это цитата, то это полная фраза, требует заглавную. Если же название - тем более. Остается вариант фразеологизма, но я что-то такого не помню...

Значит, при написании просто выдран кусок из какого-то текста, и подставленн сюда в качестве структурного синтаксического элемента, не отдельного члена предложения. И вот при такой-то структуре  "конечно" может восприниматься как

Я сначала как-то не обратил на это внимания, а теперь просто вынужден точно ради об этом упомянуть. Это совершенно сумасшедший вариант, но формально его нельзя исключить. Так что вот мне самому и приснилось. В "страшном" сне. 
Думаю, что это не очень актуально, скорее всего надо просто "конечно" писать с заглавной - и тогда все станет на свои места.